# How to convert from a Compressed Row Storage to a Compressed Column Storage of a sparse matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a relatively big (say, 5000 rows by 8000 columns) and sparse matrix that is stored in [compressed row storage](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html#sparseA) (CRS). I am trying to get its [compressed column storage](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html) (CCS) form.

Is there already an standard algorithm for doing this? One option could be reconstructing the entire matrix (40 million entries) from the CRS and then using an straightforward algorithm to obtain its  CCS. However, the time complexity of this is terrible and I plan on using this algorithm on even bigger matrices. Any other ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not as efficient as the Numerical Recipes code, but I came up with this that seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 6
#define SIZE(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))

int main() {
  float f[] = {10,-2, 3, 9, 3, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 7, 5, 8, 9, 9,13, 4, 2, 1};
  int   c[] = { 0, 4, 0, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5};
  int   r[] = { 0,    2,       5,       8,         12,         16,       19};
  float nf[SIZE(f)];
  int   nc[COLS+1] = {0};
  int   nr[SIZE(f)];
  int   nn[COLS+1];

  int rr[SIZE(f)];
  for (int k = 0, i = 0; i < SIZE(r); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < r[i+1] - r[i]; j++)
      rr[k++] = i;

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE(f); i++)
    nc[c[i]+1]++;
  for (int i = 1; i <= COLS; i++)
    nc[i] += nc[i-1];
  memcpy(nn, nc, sizeof(nc));

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE(f); i++) {
    int x = nn[c[i]]++;
    nf[x] = f[i];
    nr[x] = rr[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE(nf); i++) printf("%2.0f ", nf[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE(nr); i++) printf("%2d ", nr[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE(nc); i++) printf("%2d ", nc[i]);
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something like a standard approach as one algorithm is described in Numerical Recipes. I'll cite the code here which should give you the idea, whereas for more details you should consult chapter 2.7. of the third edition.

```
NRsparseMat NRsparseMat::transpose() const {
    Int i,j,k,index,m=nrows,n=ncols;
    NRsparseMat at(n,m,nvals); //Initialized to zero.

    //First find the column lengths for AT , i.e. the row lengths of A.
    VecInt count(m,0); //Temporary counters for each row of A.
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=col_ptr[i];j<col_ptr[i+1];j++) {
            k=row_ind[j];
            count[k]++;
        }

    for (j=0;j<m;j++) //Now set at.col_ptr. 0th entry stays 0.
        at.col_ptr[j+1]=at.col_ptr[j]+count[j];

    for(j=0;j<m;j++) //Reset counters to zero.
        count[j]=0;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++) //Main loop.
        for (j=col_ptr[i];j<col_ptr[i+1];j++) {
            k=row_ind[j];
            index=at.col_ptr[k]+count[k]; //Element’s position in column of AT .
            at.row_ind[index]=i;
            at.val[index]=val[j];
            count[k]++; //Increment counter for next element in that column.
        }
    return at;
}
```

For my personal use, I usually rewrite code from Numerical Recipes by removing it's specific typedefs (such as `Int`, `VecInt`), rename, reformat, etc.